# where to input the parameters in azure function http triger?

Tags: c#, azure, function, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

my function is published and working on Azure, if I do:

```
http://localhost:7071/api/WriteName?n=myName
```

It is working, but how can I input the parameter on the real HTTP address with the key code?:

```
http://WriteName21103515.azurewebsites.net/api/WriteName?code=7vP5MNpCK4lbif95aOwY6okKscRPDg==
```

Where do I put the `n=myName` here?

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple query variables using the & operator as follows

http://WriteName21103515.azurewebsites.net/api/WriteName?code=7vP5MNpCK4lbif95aOwY6okKscRPDg==&n=myName

If you need even more then simply add more using the & operator.

Comment: Hey, thx but it still does not work. the idea is to put ** and then & then the variables?

Comment: @ILovePizzasorry the ** is part of stack exchange format to make it bold, I edited it out now to look correctly